# Finite birational extension of $1$-dimensional Cohen-Macaulay ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay, integral-extensions

> Let $R$ be a Cohen-Macaulay ring of dimension $1$ with total ring of fractions $Q(R)$. Let $R\subseteq S \subseteq Q(R)$ be a ring such that $Q(S)=Q(R)$ and $S$ is a (module) finite extension of $R$. Hence, $S$ is a Noetherian ring of dimension $1$. Is $S$ also Cohen-Macaulay?

I can see that this is true if $R$ is reduced, because then $S$ is also reduced, and reduced rings of dimension $1$ are Cohen-Macaulay. But I am not sure what happens otherwise.

Please help.

Comment: Yes. If $R,S$ are as above , $S$ has depth one if and only if it has depth one as an $R-$module. Clearly any nonzero divisor of $R$ is a nonzero divisor of $S$.

Comment: @Mohan: Of course things are easy if $R$ and $S$ are local, but I am not necessarily assuming either of them are ...

Comment: You can reduce it to $R$ local .

Comment: @Mohan: the real problem is $S$ not being local, so one cannot talk about depth, so I do not see what you mean ... it would be nice if you could elaborate ...

Comment: If you cannot talk about depth what does CM mean to you ?

Comment: @Mohan: It means locally Cohen-Macaulay ... so like let $P$ be a prime ideal of $S$ of height $1$, and I need to show that $S_P$ has positive depth ... how do I show that?

Comment: Use localization is exact. So, if you had an injection $0\to S\stackrel{x}{\to} S$, localizing at a prime ideal $P$ of $S$, you still get an inclusion.